# NullPointer While Using a TextView to Scroll Through a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use a textview, which has a card ui applied to it, to go through my ViewPager. I'm getting a NullPointer when I set the onClickListener.

## My Code

fragment_a.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context="com.hidden.hidden.FragmentA">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/next1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
            android:text="Next" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

onCreate method inside MainActivity.java

```
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;

TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (LinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.next1);

    //NullPointer occurs here
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        }
    });

}
```

I tried putting the onClick listener in the Fragment class that goes along with fragment_a.xml but got NullPointers there because there were no items.

Here's the NullPointer:

```
06-24 10:10:17.109  14227-14227/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 14227
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hidden.hidden/com.hidden.hidden.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hidden.hidden.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

## Edit:

Here is my FragmentA class:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public FragmentA() {
        //Required empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

As I said, I tried making an onClickListener inside FragmentA like so:

```
tv1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.next1);
mPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);

tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
    }
});
```

But that code produced this:

```
06-24 10:36:36.054  18426-18426/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 18426
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hidden.hidden.FragmentA$1.onClick(FragmentA.java:33)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## Edit 2:

In following Giru Bhai's advice, I set up my FragmentA class like so:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    ViewPager mPager;
    TextView tv1;

    public FragmentA() {
        //Required empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next1);
        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Line 38
                mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Now that gives me this NullPointer:

```
06-24 10:51:15.462  24389-24389/com.hidden.hidden E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hidden.hidden, PID: 24389
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hidden.hidden.FragmentA$1.onClick(FragmentA.java:38)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Note: Line 38 is marked.

Comment: @GiruBhai I tried it and it gives me another nullpointer when the setCurrentItem method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of all the complicated code I had before, I decided to redo everything.  I now have a public mPager variable which works in MainActivity and FragmentA. MainActivity uses it to apply the ViewPager and adapter, FragmentA sets the current item when the button is clicked.

MainActivity.java

```
FragmentAdapter mAdapter;

//This was the game changer
public static ViewPager mPager;

PageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (LinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    TextView tv1;

    public FragmentA() {
        //Required empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tv1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.next1);

        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: accessing the viewpager as a static variable is bad, you should be using a callback to the activity from the fragment

Comment: @tyczj It may be but I don't know how to do that really well.

Answer (score 3):

if you are referencing someing from`fragment_a.xml` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity_main`

in your `onCreateView` of your fragment inflate the view

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
```

then use the fiew to find the textview

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.next1);
```

Comment: Little extra...even though `next1` was in `fragment_a.xml` it will still be null, because fragment view is not initialized yet. @Andrew you should inflate your textview in fragment.

Comment: @AndrewQ see my edit, you need to inflate the view then use it in the fragment

Comment: @AndrewQ you need to actually sit and look at your code, you get a null pointer on `mPager` ViewPager does not exist in the fragment, it exists at the activity level. if you want to change pages when you click on the textview you need to create a callback from the fragment to the activity to access the viewpager

Comment: @tyczj you are right,As I want to say,that is mPager is null,at line 38.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that textview  `next1` is part of `fragment_a.xml` not `activity_main`.

So either use `textview` in `activity_main` layout. or use `textview` in `onCreateView` method of fragment.

For example

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container,
                false);

       TextView  tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next1);
       tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: @AndrewQ you didn't inflate view as I suggested in my answer,Try as I suggested i.e. add rootView,it will work

Comment: @AndrewQ Please post new null pointer exception,did you return view i.e. rootview?

Comment: Yes...let me post that too.

Comment: @AndrewQ is mPager = null?

Comment: No it's set to the viewpager in xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56221/discussion-between-andrew-q-and-giru-bhai).

Comment: @AndrewQ  means what is null in line 38,is mPager?

Comment: I haven't set mPager to be null anywhere on purpose.

Comment: @AndrewQ read my comment on my answer, you need to callback to the activity to change the page

Comment: @tyczj I figured out another way. I "sat back and looked at my code" and then dumped it. I now have a public mPager variable which works in MainActivity and FragmentA. MainActivity uses it to apply the ViewPager and adapter, FragmentA sets the current item when the button is clicked.

Comment: I upvoted it but feel that my answer solved it better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndrewQ ok bro,enjoy coding.